# Sign preserving property of continuous functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function such that $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$, then prove that $f(c)=0$ for some $c$ in the interval $(a, b)$
$$$$As $f(a)>0$ , so by the sign preserving property of continuous functions there exist a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ in the interval $[a, a+\delta)$. Now $f(a+\delta)$ cannot be negative as $f(x)>0$ in $[a, a+\delta)$ and hence by the continuity of $f(x)$ at $a+\delta$ we have, $$f(a+\delta)=\lim_{x \to {a+\delta}^-}f(x)\geq 0$$ and if $f(a+\delta)>0$ then again there exists a ${\delta}_0$ such that $f(x)>0$ on the interval $[a, a+{\delta}_0)$. Proceeding in the same way we can say that $f(x)$ must be zero somewhere in the interval $(a, b)$ otherwise $f(b) \geq 0$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: The problem is "proceeding this way ...". The proof is not valid and it cannot be corrected easily.

Comment: What is the problem in "proceeding this way"?

Comment: You may never reach $b$ and if you don't reach $b$ your argument is incomplete.

Comment: @user728159 Just in case you weren't aware, you're basically trying to prove a particular case of the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), which is the stated corollary #1, i.e., there's a root in the interval, which is basically Bolzano's theorem.